# cameraCaptureDialog.ShowDialog() crashes on second push

Tags: .net, vb.net, windows-mobile

Good day everybody.

I am working on a software which is installed on a device running with Windows Mobile 6.5.
One part is using the camera of the device properly.
In my situation I want to use CameraCaptureDialog as following:

```
Dim cameraCaptureDialog As New CameraCaptureDialog()
cameraCaptureDialog.Owner = Me
cameraCaptureDialog.Mode = CameraCaptureMode.Still
If cameraCaptureDialog.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK AndAlso cameraCaptureDialog.FileName.Length > 0 Then
    Dim sFileNameExt As String = ""
    Dim sFileDir As String = ""
    Dim sPicsDir As String = ""
    Dim sFileSource As String = ""
    sFileSource = Path.GetFullPath(cameraCaptureDialog.FileName)
    sFileDir = Path.GetDirectoryName(cameraCaptureDialog.FileName)
    sFileDir = Path.GetPathRoot(cameraCaptureDialog.FileName)
    sFileNameExt = Path.GetExtension(cameraCaptureDialog.FileName)
    Dim fs As New FileStream(sFileSource, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Read)
    Dim ImgArtikel(CType(fs.Length, Int32)) As Byte
    fs.Read(ImgArtikel, 0, CType(fs.Length, Int32))
    fs.Close()
    functions.ConnectLocalDB(functions.localconn)
    Dim cmd As SqlCeCommand = functions.localconn.CreateCommand()
    cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE table SET img_Photo=@imgArt "  'assign the newly made image to db-entry
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@imgArt", SqlDbType.Image)
    cmd.Parameters("@imgArt").Value = ImgArtikel
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    cmd.Dispose()
    If File.Exists(sFileSource) Then File.Delete(sFileSource) 'delete photo after updating db

End If
cameraCaptureDialog.Dispose()
```

This works fine for the first time (both on emulator and device), but when I initiate the same event, my software crashes.
I do not get an exception when debugging it, it just crashes at ShowDialog() (forth line).

Does anyone know what's wrong here?

Comment: Does nobody have an idea on how to solve this :/ ?

Comment: Can you reduce this example further? what if you get rid of all the stuff in the If()?

Comment: Are you running this on a debugger? If not, you should. You need that exception information.

Comment: @PaulH thanks for you answer. I am running this on a debugger, but it never gets to the catch-part. I also tried to minimize the code on the important part and still encouter the same problem.

Comment: I meant that you should revise your post with the most minimal code that reproduces the problem. As for the exception, do you see anything in Visual Studio's (?) output window when your program quits? For example, a line containing the words "Data Abort".

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to set some global variable that knows that this routine is busy.

```
private cameraWorking As Boolean
```

(**Disclaimer:** Note that I don't use VB very much, so some of my syntax could be a little off, but this should give you the idea.)

I noticed that you never use `sPicsDir` you assign `sFileDir` twice.

I am also a big fan of the `Using` keyword, which is supposed to handle closing connections and disposing of objects for you.

With that in mind, I re-wrote your routine and commented out the items that are either never used or unnecessary (with the `Using` routines).

```
If Not cameraWorking Then
  Try
    cameraWorking = True
    Using cameraCaptureDialog As New CameraCaptureDialog()
      cameraCaptureDialog.Owner = Me
      cameraCaptureDialog.Mode = CameraCaptureMode.Still
      If cameraCaptureDialog.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
        Dim filename As String = cameraCaptureDialog.FileName
        If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(filename) Then
          Dim sFileSource As String = Path.GetFullPath(cameraCaptureDialog.FileName)
          'Dim sFileNameExt As String = Path.GetExtension(cameraCaptureDialog.FileName)
          'Dim sFileDir As String = Path.GetDirectoryName(cameraCaptureDialog.FileName)
          'Dim sRootDir As String = Path.GetPathRoot(cameraCaptureDialog.FileName)
          functions.ConnectLocalDB(functions.localconn)
          Using fs As New FileStream(sFileSource, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Read)
            Dim ImgArtikel(CType(fs.Length, Int32)) As Byte
            fs.Read(ImgArtikel, 0, CType(fs.Length, Int32))
            Using cmd As SqlCeCommand = functions.localconn.CreateCommand()
              cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE table SET img_Photo=@imgArt "  'assign the newly made image to db-entry
              cmd.Parameters.Add("@imgArt", SqlDbType.Image)
              cmd.Parameters("@imgArt").Value = ImgArtikel
              cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
              'cmd.Dispose()
            End Using
            ' Note that you may still need to explicitly close the stream here
            ' because the GC will likely still have it open in the call below to delete
            ' the actual file.
            fs.Close()
          End Using
          If File.Exists(sFileSource) Then
            File.Delete(sFileSource) 'delete photo after updating db
          End If
        End If
      End If
      'cameraCaptureDialog.Dispose()
    End Using
  Catch err As Exception
    MessageBox.Show(Me, err.Message, "Camera Capture Error")
  Finally
    cameraWorking = False
  End Try
```

If this all occurs as the result of a **Button Click** that is on **your** form, it would be more intuitive to set

```
My.cameraCaptureButton.Enabled = False
```

at the start of the routine, then remembering to re-enable the button in your `Finally` block.